# How do I retain a fixed drop down value in creating a link for submit?

Tags: url

I am new to the community and I am in no way an advanced programmer. I am a support in a company and would like to make our job easy in any way I can. In regards to this, could you please help me with my problem?

I have created a link wherein I want to automatically disable a program, but to do so, all values must be present. And in order to do that, I have to inspect the elements of the page and include each item in the link I am making. Here is an example below.

```
(WEBSITE)frmTarget=PROGRAM&frmOption=EDIT&program_ident=xxxxx&status=D&labor_console_mode=D
```

With the link provided above, the `labor_console_mode` part is what I want to retain. Each program_ident has a different value when it comes to the `labor_console_mode` part; sometimes it has A value, sometimes it has C value. My question is, how do I retain the value of the `labor_console_mode` part without changing its value in the link and being able to submit the whole URL.

Let us say:

```
C=Scheduled
A=Auto
D=Disabled
```

Something like, `labor_console_mode=selected` is what I thought would work but it didn't. If I remove it from the equation, the page loads saying that the `labor_console_mode` is missing. It frustrates me as to why I cannot find any answers online or if I am wrongly searching for the phrase. Please help me. I would greatly appreciate any help I can get regarding this matter.

Thank you!

Comment: anyone? please I really need help.

Comment: It is unclear what you are trying to do and how you are doing it.  Are you creating URL's by hand or using some scripting or programming language?  Please edit your question to make it clearer - please provide the original URL that works, the URL you created, what you want to happen and what actually happens.

Comment: Will do. Hold on. I will reply in a bit with the complete details. Thank you so much!

Comment: Hi. I am creating a URL by hand and by figuring out the elements of the website by pressing F12. Its not that much of what a programmer does as like I said, I am not much of one. The website I am accessing is a website that my company uses and cannot be access without a given VPN from our IT Department. 

What I am trying to do here is that I want to retain a certain value (e.g. labor console mode). Every program ident has a different value, which is why I want to keep the value of the program untouched, besides anything else.

Comment: The programs have different values for all, and the URL will not push through without the value of the labor console mode.

Comment: Please update your question with the information from your comments. Also, please include the concrete examples I requested earlier.

Comment: Anyone who can help?